# Performance issue when using ORDER BY dbms_random.value for Oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, database-cursor

I need to get 1000 random rows from a table and found solution for Oracle. But if I use this query when retrieving data from table containing large amount of rows it takes up to 3 minutes to complete:

```
SELECT column FROM
( SELECT column FROM table
ORDER BY dbms_random.value )
WHERE rownum <= 1000
```

It happens because all rows are selected and then all of them are ordered by random value when I need only 1000. Is there any workaround for such problem? Maybe using dbms_random.value along with some cursor that will pick random row.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would do that in this manner:

```
SELECT column 
FROM table sample (1)
where rownum <= 1000
--ORDER BY dbms_random.value 
 ;
```

Will get a sample of 1 percent from table, stop at first 1000 (and, if needed, order randomly) .

It is possible to exist a better way to do want you want. This is what I'll try.

Comment: The `sample` clause will return you rows in a random order: you don't need to add the `order by dbms_random.value` as well.

Comment: @ChrisSaxon yes, you're right. Maybe just to mess the mess :P

Comment: That query returns only one row at a time. But thanks a lot for that "samle" clause

Comment: @Alex I believed you need one row(caused by your query). Just get rid of outer query. Use the inner query(works even without order by).

Comment: sorry, my fault)) I need 1000 rows actually

Comment: This is an excellent answer, however one caveat is that `SAMPLE` is not *guaranteed* to return any particular number of rows; no matter how big the table is, it is possible for it to return less than 1000 records. If the number of rows in the table is sufficiently large, this should not usually be a problem.